# Debug assertion failed on class destructor

Tags: c++

I'm doing a dll in c++ and I get this error the second time I call a function:

*Debug Assertion Failed Expression: _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)*

I did some research and this seems to happen when I `delete` an object which I didn't `new`

Here is the code I think is failing

```
class tFont
{
public:
    tFont(char chars[], __int64 cods[], int count);
    ~tFont();


    int fontCount = 0;
    char* characters = NULL;
    long long* codes = NULL;

    std::vector<std::pair<char,long long>> exceptions;


    char getCharacter(long long code);


};

tFont::tFont(char chars[], long long cods[], int count)
{
    characters = new char[count];
    codes = new long long[count];
    fontCount = count;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        characters[i] = chars[i];
        codes[i] = cods[i];
    }


}


tFont::~tFont()
{

        delete[] characters;
        delete[] codes;
}
```

Visual studio stops in `delete[] characters;` after the error.

I tryied this without any luck

```
if (characters != NULL)
{
    delete[] characters;
}
if (codes != NULL)
{
    delete[] codes;
}
```

I only create one instace of this class as a static object

```
tFont* getCapFont()
{
    static tFont *capFont = NULL;

    if (capFont == NULL)
    {
        char characters[] = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' };
        long long codes[] = { 241136, 441, 183861, 102321, 45836, 5955, 19305, 7871, 220321, 102286 };
        int fontCount = 10;

        capFont = new tFont(characters, codes, fontCount);
        pair<char, long long> e;
        e.first = '0';
        e.second = 24045;

        capFont->exceptions.push_back(e);
    }

    return capFont;
}
```

Why is the destructor called even if I never do `delete capFont`

Thank you!

**Edit2**: I did as 'jarmod' said and the moment the error is thrown is when this function ends

`void analysis::singleLineTextReader(tImage img, char result[], tFont font)`

I said this happend the second time I call the function, it's possible that when `singleLineTextReader` ends calls the destructor of its parameter `font`? Which is the static object described above

Comment: Just a guess but see [Rule of 3/5/0](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). I also suggest looking at [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr), and [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).

Comment: Add some debug print statements into the various methods and see what's going on. It's probably not what you think. Also, there's no absolute need to test for NULL before calling delete, but it would be good practice to null the pointer after calling delete on it (and optionally assert that it's not null before deleting it, to catch coding errors where you've accidentally double-deleted a pointer).

Comment: After Edit2: `singleLineTextReader` gets its parameter *by value*, which means that it creates a copy of the font. The copy will contain copies of the pointers created in the constructor, and those will be deleted in the destructor. After that, the original font object will contain dangling pointers.

Comment: " I delete an object which I didn't new", why are you doing this?

Comment: @BoPersson  - *Captain Obvlious*  aaah, when I pass a parameter by copy it automatically calls the copy constructor of the class thank you both!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void analysis::singleLineTextReader(tImage img, char result[], tFont font)
```

Note that `font` is passed by value. You don't pass a pointer to it. You don't pass a reference to it. You pass its *value*.

So you are passing `singleLineTextReader` a *new* `tFont` object created by copy constructing the one you pass to it. When the destructor of the copy runs, it destroys the members of the underlying object. When you do it again, you are destroying objects already destroyed.

Follow the rule of 3/5/0. Don't make copies of objects when you don't need to.

And don't use `new`/`new[]` unless you have no choice. Here you can use all kinds of other things like vectors.

Comment: Thank you! That was the solution
I will use more pointers from now on

Comment: the proper lesson here is **fewer** pointers, esp. owning raw pointers is a nono

Comment: (facepalm at "I will use more pointers")  Use smart pointers instead.  If you change nothing except that instead of `char* characters = NULL;` you write `std::unique_ptr<char[]> characters;` (which default constructs to NULL implicitly) and get rid of `delete [] characters;` then (1) making copies accidentally will no longer be possible and (2) your lack of exception-safety due to naive destructor logic simply vanishes.  If you similarly write `std::unique_ptr<long long[]> codes;` then the compiler will write the destructor for you entirely automatically.